# cleanup tmp directory with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I use carrierwave for my images upload, in my form i added a hidden field for caching like is described in documentation.

```
= form_for @user, html: {multipart: true} do |f|
%p
  = f.label :image, "your image"
  = f.file_field :image, id: "img"
  = f.hidden_field :image_cache
```

but the problem is after uploading images and saving record, tmp directory still having all temporary/caching files.

there is a way to clean up the tmp directory ?

i found this post [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3a-Delete-cache-garbage-directories) but can't understand it as well, and there is no simple example explained

**Edit**

I tried to run this command with console

```
CarrierWave.clean_cached_files!
```

it outputs me an array of all files in tmp directory like this:

```
["/home/medBo/projects/my_project/public/uploads/tmp/1380732930-5006-6671","/hom‌​e/medBo/projects/my_project/public/uploads/tmp/1380754280-4623-3698" ....
```

but when i go to see what happens, i find that all files still exists in /tmp (not removed)

i tried to read more in the link above, i found a special considerations about **CarrierWave.clean_cached_files!** :

> Special Considerations
>
> This method breaks uploaders that have more than one version defined.
>   Your first version will be saved, but afterwards the cleanup code will
>   run and remove the tmp file that is used to generate additional
>   versions. In that case, you are better off creating a rake task that
>   cleans out the tmp folders periodically.

what means : "This method breaks uploaders that have more than one version" ? (because i use two versions in my uploader class "thumb and large versions") :

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
  ...
  ...
  version :large do
    resize_to_limit(600, 600)
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :crop_image
    resize_to_fill(100, 100)
  end
...
...
end
```

I also try to run a task to see if folders inside tmp/ directory will be removed but the task doesn't work :

```
task :delete_tmp_files do
   FileUtils.rm_rf Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/tmp/*")
end
```

Comment: Let me see what I can find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CarrierWave will take care of tidying most of the tmp files and folders for you when everything is working properly. To catch the anomalies create a custom rake task to clean up the garbage and then use the Whenever gem to schedule this task to run every day, every hour etc.

my_custom_task.rake

```
task :delete_tmp_files do
  FileUtils.rm_rf Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/where/you/store/your/tmp_images/*") #public/tmp/screenshots etc
  #note the asterisk which deletes folders and files whilst retaining the parent folder
end
```

call with `rake delete_tmp_files`

Ryan Bates has done a great railscast on setting up whenever in rails. http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby-revised

Comment: can i try your command in the last of answer with console ? my files are in /public/uploads/tmp and inside /tmp directory there is a a lot of folder which contains two version of image uploaded

Comment: when i run FileUtils.rm_rf Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/tmp it does anything, i think because your command try to remove files directly inside /tmp, but in my case i have a lot of folders in /tmp :(

Comment: there is a command to remove folders inside tmp directory rather than files ?

Comment: You can keep the directory itself and only remove only its contents by adding the "*":

FileUtils.rm_rf(Dir.glob('dir/to/remove/*'))

Comment: but there is a lot a lot of directories, each time a cache created it create a directorie with files inside, imagine how much directory will be created after a long period

Comment: Carrierwave isn't perfect, have a look at the whenever gem to automate this process everyone hour or so. I don't think you can stop carrierwave creating lots of cached files and directories, but instead of having 2 version, :large, :thumb you can just do the large resize on the standard image. Eg don't wrap the resize to limit method in the large version.

Comment: 1)- i haven't yet find the command to remove directories inside tmp/, FileUtils.rm_rf... doesn't works !! 2) - what do you mean by "you can just do the large resize on the standard image" ?

Comment: 1) Show us the exact command you are trying to delete folders inside /tmp 2) how many images are being saved when you upload an image? My guess is 3 as you have 2 versions and the original. If you apply the resize to the original image, it should mean you only save 2 images not 3, which will reduce the amount if Dirs you create. I have updated my answer to show you.

Comment: i added task at least of my question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38568/discussion-between-medbo-and-dodgerogers747)

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried calling

```
CarrierWave.clean_cached_files!
```

in your code or manually from a rails console?  Did it work?  If so, you can put it in a daily task.  You can use something like the [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever).  It will look something like:

```
every 1.day, :at => '4:30 am' do
  runner "CarrierWave.clean_cached_files!"
end
```

Comment: hi @jcm thank you a lot for trying help me :) i tried your command in console it output me an array of path's files in tmp directory something like this : ["/home/medBo/projects/my_project/public/uploads/tmp/1380732930-5006-6671","/home/medBo/projects/my_project/public/uploads/tmp/1380754280-4623-3698" .... but files still in tmp directory nothing is removed

Comment: please take look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138617/rake-aborted-operation-not-permitted-carrierwave-delete-tmp-files-that-failed, it seem that this problem is like mine, but i have some difficult to understand it

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the CarrierWave API Docs:

> clean_cached_files!(seconds = 60*60*24)
>
> Object Removes cached files which are older than one day.

If you're doing it on the console, just pass a lower value to the method, e.g.

```
CarrierWave.clean_cached_files! 1
```

Read more here:
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/carrierwave/CarrierWave/Uploader/Cache/ClassMethods